# How to group a single column based on two variables in r

Tags: r

I have a data frame with four columns in  the following format:

column 1: 0 Yellow (8 observations)
column 2: 0 Purple (9 observations)
column 3: 6 Yellow (11 observations)
column 4: 6 Purple (12 observations)

`Yellow_0 <- c(2,5,6,2,6,4,35,6,NA,NA,NA,NA)
Purple_0 <- c(12,34,34,54,23,33,2,12,23,NA,NA,NA)
Yellow_6 <- c(31,23,4,5,56,43,18,33,5,23,33,NA)
Purple_6 <- c(23,5,23,33,45,66,12,23,2,2,23,24)`

I want to group by both time (0 & 6)  and colour (Yellow and Purple). I tried the following code (after importing the csv file) which groups the variables by both time and colour (4 groups in total) instead of grouping by time (two groups) and colour(two groups).
`library(tidyverse)
library(reshape2)
DF <- melt(DF, na.rm = TRUE)
DF <- DF %>% group_by(variable)
a <- ggplot(DF, aes(x=variable, y= value, colour = variable)) + geom_boxplot()`

How do I perform "group_by" function on both Time and Colour?

Comment: Can you show few rows of dataset

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`) directly.

Comment: You can put more than one variable in `group_by` if that's what you're asking: `group_by(time, colour)`

Comment: `group_by` by itself has no effect on `ggplot2`, so that is doing nothing. If you need grouping in `ggplot2`, you need to use *its* `aes(...)` methods.

Comment: Another thought: since you're already loading the behemoth mega-meta-package `tidyverse`, use `tidyr::pivot_longer` instead of `reshape2::melt`. It has many more capabilities, is typically much simpler, and is already available to you. If you provide usable data we might be able to assist.

Comment: Thanks for your useful comments. I have now attached a screenshot of the sample data frame. The issue I have is the specifying the the "group_by" function on both time and colour owing to the organistion of the data frame.

Comment: @akrun I have attached a screenshot of my sample data frame. Thanks.

Comment: @akrun sorry about that. I have now included the 4 vectors (columns) in the body of the question. Just reiterating my issue; group by both hour (0 and 6) and by colour (Yellow and Purple). Because both variables are in the same column I cannot think of a way to restructure the data frame to group them. Many thanks.

Comment: Do you need `DF %>% pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>% separate(name, into = c('color', 'time')) %>% ggplot(aes(x = time, y = value, fill = color)) + geom_col()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could `separate` the column names into two after reshaping to 'long' format

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
DF %>%
   pivot_longer(cols = everything(), values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%
   separate(name, into = c('color', 'time')) %>%
   ggplot(aes(x = time, y = value, fill = color)) + 
         geom_boxplot() + 
         facet_wrap(~ color)
```

#### data

```
DF <- data.frame(Yellow_0, Purple_0, Yellow_6, Purple_6)
```